# How to change background color for header in DisclosureGroup in SwiftUI

Tags: swift, swiftui

I want to have expandable list in SwiftUI using DisclosureGroup.
So with the following code.

```
    struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        List {
            DisclosureGroup {
                Text("item 1")
                Text("item 2")
            } label: {
                HStack {
                    Image(systemName: "heart")
                    Text("Header")
                }
            }
            .padding()
            .background(Rectangle().fill(Color.blue))
        }
        .listStyle(.plain)
        .background(Color.red)
    }
}
```

I get such result

[image]

How to get rid of this white background or simply expand blue header to the edge of the list screen?

Answer (score 1):

The white parts you see are actually the list rows' background. You can set this to either `.clear` or `.blue` depending on what you want:

```
DisclosureGroup {
    ...
}
.listRowBackground(Color.blue) // replaces the white parts with blue
// .listRowBackground(Color.clear) // make the rows transparent, allowing you to see the red background of the list instead.
```

Answer (score -1):

Not sure of a programatic way, but you can set the size of each element to the width using a geometry reader, and then just cut off the white using some negative padding on your blue rectangle.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        GeometryReader { view in
            List {
                DisclosureGroup {
                    Text("item 1")
                        .frame(width: view.size.width, alignment: .leading)
                    Text("item 2")
                        .frame(width: view.size.width, alignment: .leading)
                } label: {
                    HStack {
                        Image(systemName: "heart")
                        Text("Header")
                    }
                }
                .padding()
                .frame(width: view.size.width, alignment: .leading)
                .background(
                    Rectangle()
                        .fill(.blue)
                        .padding(-12)
                )
            }
            .listStyle(.plain)
            .background(Color.red)
        }
    }
}
```